# How to detect single word in a div

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, text

For an instance, I have a block that looks like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/9varxzff/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">Hello! this is my new space where i can show you something</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
```

Output: https://www.screencast.com/t/KyqNeWRT

Here you can see, that word "something" normally transferred to a new line.
I need to increase or decrease font-size of all text in a div in order to remove this single word e.g. make 2 rows or add word "you" to the third row.

I'm already found the solution for this issue, but something wrong with my algorithm and I can't predict it's behavior.

Here it is:

1. Get width of the container with text
2. Place text to a canvas and get it's width in px
3. text_width / container_width = rows amount (e.g. 2.85 stands for 2 full rows and 85% of fourth row)
4. If incomplete row less than 30% of full row, increase or decrease font size

I think the problem is with third point, because sometimes I have 1.87 rows but in fact i have 3 rows with a single word in a third row.

This is my code, open console to get more info about current process

https://jsfiddle.net/9varxzff/6/

Maybe my algorithm is wrong at all - suggest better way to resolve this problem.  If not help me to improve my current algorithm. Thank you :)

Comment: Using [monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) would make your job much easier. Then your calculations will be much much simpler & with use of one or two of simple js string parsing functions you can make it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Clone div and set its text as substring till last space.
- Compare height of both divs using `div.offsetHeight`.
- If height is same, there are more than 1 word.
- If not, it had only 1 word in last line.

You can use following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/9varxzff/7/) to test/ debug code.

```js
function hasTrailingWord(selector) {
  var div = document.querySelector(selector);
  var clone = div.cloneNode(false);
  var index = div.textContent.lastIndexOf(" ")

  clone.classList.add('hide')
  clone.textContent = div.textContent.substring(0, index);
  document.body.append(clone)

  var h1 = div.offsetHeight;
  var h2 = clone.offsetHeight;
  
  console.log(h1, h2)
  clone.remove()
  return h1 !== h2;
}

console.log(hasTrailingWord(".container"))
console.log(hasTrailingWord(".container1"))
```

```css
[class^=container] {
  width: 200px;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Hello! this is my new space where i can show you something</div>

<br/>

<div class="container1">Hello! this is my new space where i can show you something for you to test</div>
```